# EJB interface references from a separated Web Project

Tags: eclipse, servlets, jakarta-ee, ejb, wildfly

I am doing some EJB 3.1 practices on Eclipse.

I have an EJB Project and a Dynamic Web Project on Wildfly 9.

What I am trying to do is to call an EJB method
(the EJB Project) from a Servlet (in the Dynamic Web Project) 
using a @EJB annotation on the Servlet code:

```
@EJB
IBeanRemote bean; //realize the bean variable is declared as the remote EJB Interfase.

protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse    response) throws ServletException, IOException {    
    response.getWriter().println(bean.getMethod());
}
```

and my EJB is pretty simple:

```
@Remote
@Stateless
public interfase IBeanRemote {
   public String getMethod();
}
...
public BeanRemote extends IBeanRemote
{
    @Override
    public String getMethod() { 
        return "How to call this ejb?"; 
    }
}
```

Both projects are being packaged into a EAR Project, but I am not able to
see the IBeanRemote type reference from the Web Project (because IBeanRemote and the Servlet are in separated projects), so, the line

```
@EJB
IBeanRemote bean;
```

can not be compiled.

A common solution could be by adding the EJB project in the Web Project Build Path, but it makes no sense if I am using a Remote EJB that runs on a very remote Server and I suppose the Web Project should not know anything about the EJB implementation.

How can I get the IRemoteBean reference type into my Web Project in order to make my Servlet class
compile and call the EJB method in eclipse?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why don't you separate your EJB project to 2 smaller projects: EJB-API which contains the interface and you can use this project for your client, and EJB-IMPL which implements the interface. Both your client and EJB-IMPL will have the reference to your EJB-API project.

Comment: Actually I just realized that we can create automatically an ejb client jar in eclipse by checking this option when we are creating the EJB Project inside an EAR. Only the ejb interfaces will be exported to the client jar. Great, thanks.